# Can't format number in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, number-formatting

I'm using PHPExcel to print some money amount, and I need them to have 4 decimal numbers after comma, but I want to remove any trailing zero. For example, my input is:

```
 Input: 11,1230 => Wanted output: 11,123
 Input: 0,0123  => Wanted output: 0,0123
 Input: 8,3200  => Wanted output: 8,32
 Input: 44,0000 => Wanted output: 44     <--error is here
```

The problem is that I can't get rid of the trailing comma of `44,0000` which prints out as `44,`

I'm using the following command:

```
$activeSheet->getStyle("K10")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('€ ####0.####');
```

All numbers print as expected except for those numbers without significant decimals value, like 44,0000. Any idea?

EDIT: I know I can use MS Excel to achieve this, by using these buttons

[image]

but I would prefer a PHP solution

Comment: what is your decimal separator? e.g. 1/2 = 0.5 or 0,5?

Comment: 0,5 like in the examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to use

```
€ ####0.0000
```

or

```
€ ####0.0###
```

rather than

```
€ ####0.####
```

The `#` is telling MS Excel only to display digits in that position where necessary, whereas `0` is telling MS Excel always to display digits in that position (even if that digit is only a `0`)

But if you use `.####`, MS Excel will always display the decimal separator, even if there are no digits to display following it unless you use conditional formatting with a formula like `=MOD(A1,1)>0`

Comment: I tried with ####0.0### which seems to be the best format, but still prints out `44,`

Comment: Well it should print `44,0`, because it's explicitly telling MS Excel to format the value to always display at least one digit after the decimal, even if that digit is a `0`

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant `44,0`. But I would live to remove the unnecessary `,0`

Comment: It will, as my answer said, the only way to suppress the decimal separator is using conditional formatting to set different masks if the value is integer or float... this isn't a PHPExcel limitation, it's a limitation of MS Excel number formatting

Comment: Mmmm maybe I can check if the number has decimals before setting the cell format, and then decide according to it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a solution from excel because your final result will be visible from a excel sheet and your requirement seems not to be possible only using number formatting. My suggestion is to add conditional number formatting from PHPExcel. [Here](http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/09/05/show-decimal-points-if-needed/) shows how it is done using excel.

**OR**

You may have to override PHPExcel classes.

Comment: Thank you, but this would mean losing time afterwards, which is something I would like to avoid. Overridding PHPExcel is actually the best way to get it to work